# (Python) Como puedo extraer parte de un string y moverla a una nueva columna de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

espero puedan ayudarme!.

Tengo las siguientes columnas de un Dataframe, y como se puede observar, las columnas se componen de la fecha y la hora. Quisiera separar la hora para que quedase en una columna aparte.

[image: Datadrame]

lo que intento hacer es contar las cuantos tickets se presentaron en un mismo día, independientemente de la hora, y así representarlos en una serie de tiempo.
hasta ahora solo he podido filtrarlos por su categoría.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_excel("Tickets-June-04-2019-13_15.xlsx") 
"""Filtrando tickets Urgentes"""
tickets_urgentes = dataset.loc[:, "prioridad"]
tickets_urgentes = tickets_urgentes == "Urgent"
tickets_urgentes = dataset[tickets_urgentes]


"""Filtrando tickets Altos"""
#Seleccionar la columna
tickets_altos = dataset.loc[:, "prioridad"] 
#Filtrar por prioridad
tickets_altos = tickets_altos == "High"
tickets_altos = dataset[tickets_altos]


"""Filtrando Tickets Medios"""
tickets_medios = dataset.loc[:, "prioridad"]
tickets_medios = tickets_medios == "Medium"
tickets_medios = dataset[tickets_medios]


"""Filtrando Tickets Bajos"""
tickets_bajos = dataset.loc[:, "prioridad"]
tickets_bajos = tickets_bajos == "Low"
tickets_bajos = dataset[tickets_bajos]
```

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Por favor adjunta tu código, para podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Por favor, explica un poca más lo que necesitas. Para cualquier cálculo es mejor tener fecha y hora juntos en la tabla, y emplear funciones para solo extraer lo que necesitas en cada momento.

Comment: Hola! ya he editado la pregunta y añadido el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre que podes hacer es separarlo por el espacio que tenes entre medio de la fecha y la hora, se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
#Dividir el dataset con el delimitador "espacio"
separado = dataset["Hora Creacion"].str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)

#Al resultado del split lo ponemos en la primera columna
dataset["Hora C"]= separado[0]

#Hacemos lo mismo con la segunda columna
dataset["Fecha C"]= separado[1]

#Paso opcional, borramos la columna original
dataset.drop(columns =["Hora Creacion"], inplace = True)
```

Marca la respuesta como correcta si te sirvió. Saludos.

Comment: Si funcionó!
Muchísimas Gracias!

Comment: Lo que me di cuenta recién es que puse al revés los nombres, fecha es hora y hora es fecha.

Comment: Si, me di cuenta de ello, pero ya lo he corregido.
Nuevamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @JuanPabloMadriaga quiero extraer la latitud y longitud de una columna de un dataframe  que viene así: (Decimal('11.327245'), Decimal('126.652487')), alguna forma de extraer solo estos números?

Comment: Si tenes los simbolos ' (comilla simple) podes hacer un split y te quedas con los numeros